# What is the meaning of this feature “Camera, recently”

Tags: iphone

I am using an iPhone 11 with iOS on 14.4.2.

I have noticed that there is a hint text after taking a video clip. I know this question might sound stupid but what is the meaning of the feature? In what situation should I need to see this hint?

Thanks for any tips.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that an app has used your camera recently - in this case, the Camera app.

If you see an orange dot at the top of your screen, then an app is recording audio. If you see a green dot, then an app is recording video (with or without audio). In either case, the control center will tell you which app it is/was for a short time after it's over.

If you didn't expect an app to be using your audio or video, then this helps you understand what happened, so you know which app is abusing your privacy.

[About the orange and green indicators in your iPhone status bar](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211876)

Comment: Thanks Joe! I’m glad that apple is protecting my privacy